# Receiving exit code -1073741819 when program is ran

Tags: c

I'm making a tic-tac-toe program in C. My code is listed below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

char evaluateWinConditions(char board[3][3]);

int main(void)
{
    puts("---");
    puts("---");
    puts("---");

    char board[3][3] = {{"-"}}; // board

    char key = 0; // stores key presses

    // stores position of mouse pointer
    int row = 1;
    int column = 1;

    // stores player turn
    int player = 1;

    printf("\033[%d;%dH", row, column);

    while (evaluateWinConditions(board) == 0) {
        key = _getch();

        switch (key) {
            case 'a':
                column -= 1;
                break;
            case 'w':
                row -= 1;
                break;
            case 'd':
                column += 1;
                break;
            case 's':
                row += 1;
                break;
            case ' ':
                if (player == 1) {
                    printf("%c", 'X');

                    board[row][column] = 'X';

                    player = 2;
                }
                else {
                    printf("%c", 'O');

                    board[row][column] == 'O';

                    player = 1;
                }

                break;
        }

        printf("\033[%d;%dH", row, column);
    }

    printf("\033[5;1H");

    if (evaluateWinConditions(board == 1)) printf("Player 1 wins.");
    else printf("Player 2 wins.");
}

char evaluateWinConditions(char board[3][3])
{
    if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] ||
        board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] ||
        board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] ||
        board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] ||
        board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0]) {
        if (board[0][0] == "X") return 1;
        else return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I compile the program, there's no errors. However, I receive a run time error with code -1073741819 when I run the program. I'm using Windows 10 64-bit and Visual Studio 2019. This error appears after about one second when I run the program. When I debug the program in Visual Studio, I receive an error on line 74 "Exception thrown: read access violation; board was nullptr"

Comment: `char board[3][3] = {"-"};` - this wil only initialize a single element of the arrays. The rest will be zeros. Also characters are written in single quotes. This applies to your comparisons too such as `board[row][column] = "X";`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and fix the warnings. A single character is e.g. `'X'` not `"X"`. The latter is a string literal. This is important when assigning or comparing a single element of `board`. Wrong parentheses: `while (evaluateWinConditions(board == 0))`, do you mean `while (evaluateWinConditions(board )== 0)`? Additional hint: Instead of `case 97: // a` use `case 'a':`

Comment: Alright, I made the changes you listed. I also changed the code listed accordingly

Comment: And what happened? And no, you are not supposed to change the question, because it is supposed to remain a question.

Comment: I still have the same error.

Comment: -1073741819 matches the NT status code `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` except that the original unsigned 32-bit value 0xC0000005 has been interpreted as a signed 32-bit value.

Comment: Also should probably mention when I comment out the calls to evaluateWinConditions I don't have any errors.

Comment: Your code has **a lot of** problems. Please enable all warnings and fix one by one.

Comment: Your first `if` in the `evaluateWinConditions()` function does not do what you assume it does.

Comment: `board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2]` doesn't mean what you think it means. I think you mean `board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2]` or `board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][0] == board[0][2]`.

Comment: I'm not receiving any warnings strangely

Comment: Can't be. Which compiler are you using and how do you invoke it?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019's default compiler. I'm just doing Ctrl+F5 which automatically compiles and runs and F5 to debug

Comment: ok, don't have this one in reach to comment

Comment: alright i fixed the if statement issues i think

Comment: I'm still getting the same error when debugging though

Comment: Here - I put your code into online `gcc` compiler, removing the `conio.h` and `_getch` as these are not supported. Now work to fix all of the warnings: https://wandbox.org/permlink/w9ZWpsBRWTxjDrAu . Once it is clean, take the code back to VS.

Comment: Okay, I found out the warnings are only displayed in code analysis so I fixed those

Comment: `column -= 1;` better as `if (column > 0) column -= 1;` likewise for other code.

Comment: Alright so the program is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable cause of the exception is a consequence of the nonsensical comparison `board == 1` in the function call `evaluateWinConditions(board == 1)`. The `board == 1` comparison is a constraint violation (use of equality operator between pointer and integer that isn't a null pointer constant) that is probably evaluating to the `int` value 0, and that `int` value 0 (which is not a null pointer constant here) is probably being converted in an implementation-defined way to a null pointer (which is another constraint violation due to lack of an explicit cast) of type `char (*)[3]` to become the value of the `board` parameter in the `evaluateWinConditions` function. The `evaluateWinConditions` function is dereferencing that null pointer, resulting in an access violation exception.

There are plenty of other errors in the original code.